# Connecting to mysql for a Spotify App

Tags: mysql, spotify

Is it possible to connect to a mysql database in a Spotify app? I added mysql to the required permissions, but it shows the whole php code. I want to add mysql because of a search function.

Answer (score 4):

PHP is not supported in Spotify Apps. Only HTML, CSS, and JavaScript are officially supported.([Source](http://developer.spotify.com/en/spotify-apps-api/overview/))

Maybe you could make a backend on your server that you can access with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

in your manifest.json add

```
"RequiredPermissions": [
        "http://your.site.com",
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com",  
           ]
```

In your app add

```
  $.getJSON("http://your.site.com/get_variable.php", { "variable": variable },
    function(data) {
      //do something with the returned data
    }
  ).error(function() { console.log("error getting variable"); });
```

On your server add a file get_variable.php that does your sql

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user_name","password");

if (!$con){
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected=mysql_select_db("database_name", $con);

if (!$db_selected){
  die ("Can\'t use database_name : " . mysql_error());
}

$variable = $_GET["variable"];
$sql = "your sql using $variable" 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$search_results=array(); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  //add data from $row into $search_results
}
echo json_encode($search_results);
```